# How to get value from Native Storage ZoneAwarePromise in Ionic 4

Tags: javascript, typescript, hybrid-mobile-app, ionic4

I am trying to get value from Native Storage with Service and Promise but  i am getting value as ZoneAwarePromise

Inside Service:

```
  async getDataStorage(key:any): Promise<any>{
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      this.nativeStorage.getItem(key).then( res => resolve(res))
    });
  }
```

Inside class for accessing data from service function:

```
  newReq["sessionId"] = this.getSessionID();
  getSessionID(){
    var result = this.storageService.getDataStorage("sessionId");
    return result;
  }
```

Got Result:

```
{
sessionId: ZoneAwarePromise
__zone_symbol__state: true
__zone_symbol__value: {key: "20193251243251135926242866255036198243"}
__proto__: Object
}
```

Required Result:

```
{key: "20193251243251135926242866255036198243"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following:

```
newReq["sessionId"] = this.getSessionID();
getSessionID(){
  this.storageService.getDataStorage("sessionId").then((result) => {
    return result;
  });  
}
```